Measuring frequency and duty cycle of LM2596s module

Are those the correct points to measure the frequency and duty cycle of the IC chip?
Positive probe at the output pin(2)of the IC
and the common probe at ground.
(see attached photo).

Yes, it is. Use a 10:1 probe if available.

Make sure IN- is at ground before you connect your scope ground as well.

@user1850479,what do you mean:to make sure that IN(i assume you refer to pin number 1)is at ground?since this VIN is connected to the positive of the power source.May you explain?

You have two inputs, IN+ and IN-. You need to make sure that IN- is at ground before you connect a ground lead on an oscilloscope to it or you will cause a short circuit.
